# mongodb: одновременная запись одинаковых данных в коллекцию, как избежать?

Tags: mongodb

Существует коллекция "counter" с полем "value", которое хранит натуральное число. Существует кнопка на веб странице, при нажатии на которую отправляется post-запрос в некий обработчик, который подключен к mongodb. Этот обработчик, при поступлении запроса, добавляет в коллекцию новую запись, которая равна db.counter.find().length() + 1. По условию, каждая новая запись содержит value, который на единицу больше value предыдущей записи, и все они идут по порядку. В случае одного пользователя, нажимающего кнопку, эта логика будет работать, однако в случае появления второго пользователя возникает риск одновременного нажатия кнопки, и дублирования значения db.counter.value. Причем по условию, я не могу использовать блокировку по коллекциям/документам.  Эдакая коллизия, какими способами я могу избежать ее?

Comment: Это невозможно без пессимистичной или оптимистичной блокировки. Вы можете возложить это на монгу (с помощью [уникального индекса](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/)) или выполнять сами с помощью аналога CAS-операции (insert if not exists, по-быстрому найти не удалось). В любом случае вы скорее всего делаете автоинкремент на коленке, который вам на самом деле вообще не нужен - лучше использовать UUID.

Comment: @Etki все верно, нужен собственный инкремент. Грубо говоря, мне нужен человеко-понятный id для некоей сущности, вида /^[0-9]{1,12}$/. Спасибо, почитаю про индексацию.